# Как правильно разбить строку на слова

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe2

**Как строки вот такого вида:**

```
1. Космос 2. Nastasia 3. mamochka.dochka0702 4. kyklabratz 5. ProstoTanya 6. Olga135
```

**Разбить таким образом что бы на выходе получились только имена и в столбик. То есть вот так:**

```
Космос
Nastasia
mamochka.dochka0702
kyklabratz
ProstoTanya
Olga135
```

Пробовала вот так сделать. Но тогда и цифры через одну добавляются.:

```
function StringToItems (inText: string; delimChar: Char): string;
begin
  Result := StringReplace(inText, delimChar, #13#10, [rfReplaceAll]);
end;

// И использую вот так
S := StringToItems(s, ' ');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
  prev: string;
  str: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  str := '1. Космос 2. Nastasia 3. mamochka.dochka0702 4. kyklabratz 5. ProstoTanya 6. Olga135';
  prev := '';
  i := 1;

  while (prev <> str) do
  begin
    prev := str;
    str := StringReplace(str, IntToStr(i) + '. ', #13#10, [rfReplaceAll]);
    Inc(i);
  end;

  WriteLn(str);
end;
```